# Reverse output in sed

Tags: sed

**test.sed:**

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef

/^(1|\+1)\(([0-9]{3})\)(555)-([0-9]{4})/d
/^\(([0-9]{3})\)(555)-([0-9]{4})/d
```

**file.txt:**

```
(123)456-7890
1(123)456-7890
+1(123)456-7890

(123)555-7890
1(123)555-7890
+1(123)555-7890

(416)736-5053
1(416)736-2100
+1(416)736-2100
```

**Current Output:**

```
(123)456-7890
1(123)456-7890
+1(123)456-7890


(416)736-5053
1(416)736-2100
+1(416)736-2100
```

**Expected Output:**

```
(123)555-7890
1(123)555-7890
+1(123)555-7890
```

Hello. I want to have Expected Output as above, which is just picking up 3 sentences which are not picked up in current output.

Is there a way to do that by having -Ef flag? you can add more flag, but I can't delete these flag.

**I tried like following, which didn't work:**

```
/^(1|\+1)\(([0-9]{3})\)(555)-([0-9]{4})/p
/^\(([0-9]{3})\)(555)-([0-9]{4})/p
```

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve, instead of having people parse your regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

**test.sed:**

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef
/\([0-9]{3}\)555-[0-9]{4}/!d
```

---

Command:

```
sed -Ef test.sed file.txt
```

The output:

```
(123)555-7890
1(123)555-7890
+1(123)555-7890
```